# How to change the Font of a SpanLabel in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

Why can't I set the font of a SpanLabel of Codename One?

```
SpanLabel title = new SpanLabel("SpanLabel");
title.getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_LARGE));
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SpanLabel title = new SpanLabel("SpanLabel");
        **title.getTextAllStyles()**.setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_LARGE));
```

To change style of spanlabel getTextAllStyle method should be called as shown in above code

Comment: Any idea why? What happens when just `getAllStyles` gets used? Without you answer, I guess, I could lose a few hours on this.